# 18.04 — Configure X to be started by non root user

Tags: 18.04, xorg, systemd, kiosk

I am trying to setup ubuntu 18.04 LTS as a kiosk system, so I have installed xorg, openbox and chromium. If I start the machine log in as a non root user and run `startx`, `X` starts a blank openbox desktop, as expected.

To run everything on start, I have created `/etc/systemd/system/kiosk.service` with that content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kiosk Launcher
# That is copied from /lib/systemd/system/gdm.service
# maybe needed ??
# After=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
User=tmil
# That is taken from https://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/
# ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "startx /etc/X11/Xsession /opt/kiosk.sh"
ExecStart=/opt/kiosk.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and `/opt/kiosk.sh` with that content:

```
#!/bin/bash
startx
```

What results in that error: [pasetbin](https://pastebin.com/FM5ycak0)

I am just guessing that this is a permission issue, since that command:

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common
```

yields that error:

```
 update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
```

instead of letting me select »Anybody« to be able to run X

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?